# Linq To Entities: Checking Multiple Columns Against against a Set of Values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, where-clause, multiple-columns

I have a MySQL DB that I'm trying to query with the Entity Framework.

I have a Match table that looks like this:

match_id,  winning_hero1,  winning_hero2,  winning_hero3,  winning_hero4,  winning_hero5

with a winning_hero being identified by an integer.

given a list of hero ids, I want to return all matches where these heroes were all on the winning team together.

something like this:

```
public List<MatchEntity> GetAllMatchesWithWinningHeroes(List<int> heroList)
    {
        List<MatchEntity> matchList = null;
        using (var context = new dotaEntities())
        {
            switch (heroList.Count)
            {
                case 1:
                    matchList = context.MatchEntities.Where(m => m.winning_hero1 == heroList[0]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero2 == heroList[0]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero3 == heroList[0]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero4 == heroList[0]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero5 == heroList[0]).ToList();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    matchList = context.MatchEntities.Where(m => (m.winning_hero1 == heroList[0]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero2 == heroList[0]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero3 == heroList[0]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero4 == heroList[0]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero5 == heroList[0])
                                                                 && (m.winning_hero1 == heroList[1]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero2 == heroList[1]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero3 == heroList[1]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero4 == heroList[1]
                                                                 || m.winning_hero5 == heroList[1])).ToList();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //etc..
            }

            return matchList;
        }
    }
```

Is there a "nicer" way to go about selecting these matches?

Thank you.

Comment: A nicer way is to have a winning_hero collection rather than 5 separate winning_heros.

Comment: Your data design is wrong. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
using (var context = new dotaEntities())
{
  matchList = context.MatchEntities.Where(m=> 
    ( heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero1)?1:0 + 
      heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero2)?1:0 +
      heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero3)?1:0 +
      heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero4)?1:0 +
      heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero5)?1:0
    ) == heroList.Count
  ).ToList();
}
```

This assumes that all winning_heros are different.

Comment: I usually don't downvote, but this answer definitely calls for one. Why don't you use AND instead?

Comment: With AND, all winning_heros have to belong to heroList. That is not what the user wants. He wants that all elements in heroList are included in the winning_heros.

Comment: In that case, the heroList should always have 5 heroes, otherwise it doesn't even make sense to check if all the heroes are in the same match. Anyway, as I mentioned in my answer, the data design has to be fixed.

Comment: If the heroList contains 2 elements, and for example m.winning_hero3==heroList[0], and m.winning_hero4==heroList[1], the sum will be 2, equal to heroList.Count. I think this is what the user wants, All elements in heroList to be included in at least one of the winning_heros. I agree that the DB design is not normalized but that is a different issue.

Comment: I want the user to be able to select combos of heroes and see if they won a match together.  Anyway, I will change the data design.  I knew it was wrong when I was implementing it, but I figured it might be easier for seeing which combos of heroes won more often, I see now that it's much better just to go with a better design.  Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: If this is what the user wants, your answer is correct. I'll remove the downvote. But, it doesn't make much sense to me. The data design has to be normalized.

Comment: Apparently, I can't remove my downvote. It says you last voted 25 mins ago.

Comment: Yes, heroList should have 5 different heros max, if there are more than 5 there is not possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
using (var context = new dotaEntities())
{
  var matchList = context.MatchEntities.Where(m => 
    heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero1) &&
    heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero2) && 
    heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero3) && 
    heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero4) && 
    heroList.Contains(m.winning_hero5)).ToList();
}
```

But, your data design is wrong. In your Match table, you should only have a MatchID (PK), and probably MatchName or MatchDate, and in your Hero table, you should have HeroID (PK), HeroName,... Then, you should have a third table (MatchHero) just to create a many-to-many relationship between the two tables. In your MatchHero table, you'll have MatchID and HeroID.